# Why MySQL substr returns value in data type Text when length is over 512?

Tags: mysql, text, varchar, substr

I've noticed that MySQL substr() returns value in data type text when the length is over 512.

Please check the example below;

Data table:

```
create table temp10( c0 int primary key auto_increment, c1 varchar(2500));
insert into temp10(c1) values ('abcd');
```

Secondary table using temp10 as source;

```
create table temp11 as
    select c1, 
    substr(c1, 1, 10) as c2, 
    substr(c1, 1, 100) as c3, 
    substr(c1, 1, 512) as c4, 
    substr(c1, 1, 513) as c5, 
    substr(c1, 1, 2500) as c6
    from temp10;
```

Structure of the table created is;

Table: temp11
Columns:

```
c1 varchar(2500) 
c2 varchar(10) 
c3 varchar(100) 
c4 varchar(512) 
c5 text 
c6 text
```

Is this an expected/ documented behavior?

This same behavior has been noticed for subqueries nested within select clause too.

Comment: Good observation.  It does not seem to be covered in the documentation, as far as I can see.  Here is a demonstration of the issue:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b101e11ab2b463ed831b4db6c94e666a.

Comment: the main problem is the max row size and if you take text it is stored "outside", so a good choice to use TEXT